# RegEx on javascript: Searching for ID with Exclusion of some whole numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this String: **value268_generated_number**

I usually do this : `^value.*_generated_number`

How will I match my regex but **NOT** with these numbers: **1,10 and 100** after the word "value" ?

e.g:

- value1_generated_number
- value10_generated_number
- value100_generated_number

The expression should also meet generated numbers up to 50000.

Comment: What do you want the result to look like? So if the string is "value100_42", the output you want is...?

Comment: @epascarello No. The "generated_number" is a literal word. my examples are the exclusions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^value(?!10{0,2}_).*?_generated_number
```

Also note that you should be careful using the `*` quantifier with `.`. It usually matches more than you want it to. Better replace `*` with a character class, e.g. `\d*`. I made the quantifier lazy, just to be on the safe side.

If your input is always of the form `value<digits>_<digits>`, then the final expression would be:

```
^value(?!10{0,2}_)\d*_\d+$
```

Comment: I would replace `0?0?` with `0{0,2}` for clarity.

Comment: `?` is not required..you should use `\d+`

Comment: @kolink The expression failed to match to any numbers that starts with 1. e.g. 1000, 105, 101, etc.. the only excluded whole numbers are 1, 10 and 100 . Thanks

Comment: @Raf: Your example list was not exhaustive enough... I update my answer.